# Неверная структура запроса

Tags: python, python-3.x, post, requests

Задача: Отправляем номер телефона и смс, получаем сообщение с токеном. Получаем сообщение с ошибкой Wrong request struct

Запрос:

```
tok_en = requests.post(url_send_token, json={"phone": number_phone, "code": cod})
token = tok_en.text
print(token)
```

Вот сообщение:

> {"meta":{"message":"Wrong request
> struct","type":"error","error":400,"date":"2021-03-2"},"data":{"date":""}}

Что не так?

Comment: Хз, смотрите в инспекторе браузера как это запрос через сайт заполняется, спрашивайте у разрабов сайта. А так, мб ему не хватает поля `date`, иначе не знаю почему в ошибке про него написано :)

Comment: @ gil9red В том и беда( кидаю руками, все норм, а в скрипте... Здесь поля access_token не хватает, где и должен быть токен

Comment: Нужно указывать все поля из запроса

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот ответ: В переменную cod передавалось вот так ('2345',) И надо просто выбрать по индексу и получилось 2345 и выглядит так:

```
tok_en = requests.post(url_send_token, json={"phone": number_phone, "code": cod[0]})
token = tok_en.text
print(token)
```